# $this->Auth->user() work but when i add id $this->Auth->user('id') is null

Tags: authentication, cakephp

this is my output when i write : $this->Auth->user() but when i add id $this->Auth->user('id') is null
[the ime of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fjeo.png)

Plz what can i do ?

Comment: Can you try $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id'); instead and see if that works?

Comment: i try it but it don't work :(

Comment: What happens if you do pr($this->Session->read('Auth.User')); and pr($this->Session->read('Auth.User.0'));

Comment: when i try $this->Session->read('Auth.User') it work and print the same thing than $this->Auth->user()  and when i try $this->Session->read('Auth.User.0') it print the same thing but (int) 0 => array is removed

Comment: thanks it wor thanks you sooo muchhhh

Comment: You shouldn't really have a 0 key after User unless for a specific reason, it could potentially conflict with third party code, I'd suggest you post code snippets to have this fixed moving forward.

Comment: yeah it work thanks you soo much. plz have you an idea how shoud i write in the index to let each user see his own bien without see the others biens